# Eliminar espacios en blanco en C

Tags: c, string

Quiero eliminar los espacios en blanco de una frase que está en un string, no en un array palabra por palabra.

Tengo esto:

```
  char contar;
  FILE *ejercicio;
  FILE *nuevo;

 /*Aquí abro los archivos donde lee y donde escribe pero no escribo esa parte*/

  while(!feof(ejercicio)){
       contar = fgetc(ejercicio);
       printf("%c", contar);

       fprintf(nuevo, "%c", contar); /*tengo que añadir algo aquí pero no sé qué*/
 }
```

Me gustaría hacerlo sin tener que recurrir a arrays, ¿alguna idea?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes condicionar tu bucle para que cuando lea un espacio no lo imprima. Más o menos así:

```
  char contar;
  FILE *ejercicio;
  FILE *nuevo;


 /*Aquí abro los archivos donde lee y donde escribe pero no escribo esa parte*/

  while(!feof(ejercicio)){
       contar = fgetc(ejercicio);
       printf("%c", contar);

       if(contar != ' '){ //Si 'contar' no es un espacio imprimir
          fprintf(nuevo, "%c", contar); /*tengo que añadir algo aquí pero no sé qué*/
       }
 }
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto Dionicio! Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias!!